# A question on a sequence of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x_n=\frac{n}{e}-[\frac{n}{e}]$. What is the set of limits of subsequences of $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$?

Comment: it seems there is no limit for it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a standard theorem that if $\alpha$ is an irrational number, then the set of **fractional parts** of $n\alpha$, as $n$ ranges over the positive integers, is **dense** in the interval $[0,1]$. But $\dfrac{1}{e}$ is irrational. So every point in $[0,1]$ is the limit of a subsequence of your sequence. And nothing else is, since all your numbers are in $[0,1]$.

**Remark:** One does not need the general theorem about irrationals to prove the result: all we need to do is to imitate the proof. For consider the series expansion 
$$\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!}-\frac{1}{5!}+\cdots$$
of $e^{-1}$. By cutting off the expansion at a large **odd** number $b$, we can make $\dfrac{b!}{e}-\left\lfloor\dfrac{b!}{e}\right\rfloor$ as small positive as we wish, say $\lt \epsilon$.  It follows that the numbers  $\dfrac{b!k}{e}-\left\lfloor\dfrac{b!k}{e}\right\rfloor$ come within distance $\lt \epsilon$ of every number between $0$ and $1$.